# Fibonacci One Recursive Call

Tags: c

I wish to transform the basic Fibonacci function:

```
int find_fib(int fib_to) {

    if (fib_to == 0) {
        return 0;

    }
    else if (fib_to == 1) {
        return 1;

    }
    else {
        return (find_fib(fib_to - 1) + find_fib(fib_to - 2));       
    }   
}
```

into one that would use only ONE recursive call. I searched up many sites that tells me to store the value found by (find_fib(fib_to - 1) + find_fib(fib_to - 2)) into some array and then make use of the array, but doing so requires 2 recursive calls.

Any tips on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Write a loop that keeps the last 2 values and computes the next one.

Comment: chqrlie's comment translated in recursion: "you need to add arguments to your recursive function that would store the last two results of fib"

Comment: How about ZERO recursive calls, will that do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24537352/971127

Comment: @barak we are required to use recursion

Comment: See the question @BLUEPIXY linked to. It contains the single-recursion call version. The actual question is about something completely different, hence why it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibonacci(int number_iterations, int number_a, int number_b) 
{
    if(number_iterations <= 0) {
        printf("error: 'number_iterations' must be >= 1\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(number_iterations == 1) {
        printf("%d ", number_a + number_b);
        return number_a + number_b;
    }

    printf("%d ", number_a + number_b);
    return fibonacci(number_iterations - 1, number_b, number_a + number_b);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1; 
    int b = 1;
    int number_of_iterations = 0;

    printf("Enter a number >= 1: ");

    int err = scanf("%d", &number_of_iterations);
    int final_result = -1;

    if (err != EOF) {
        printf("fibonacci: %d %d ", a, b);
        final_result = fibonacci(number_of_iterations, a, b);
    }

    printf("Final fibonacci: %d\n", final_result);

    return 0;
}
```

would return you:

```
Enter a number >= 1: 10
fibonacci: 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144
Final fibonacci: 144
```

Comment: Yeah that is similar to what the output result is, but I only need the user to enter the number and then print out the fib of that number (instead of the entire string of fibs).

Comment: Very simple fix,  don't printout anything until after the last index is calculated.  Suggest have main() pay attention to the final returned value, as that is what you want to print.

Answer (score 0):

you could do the following:

```
def fibonacci(n):
cache = {0: 1, 1: 1}

if n in cache:
    return cache[n]
else:
    cache[n] = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
return cache[n]
```

By using a dictionary to store the key/values of the output of a fibonacci number, you avoid duplicate recursions and also it will return the values of the fib number.

More on this topic and better optimization can be found in this page.

https://realpython.com/fibonacci-sequence-python/